# Dynamically created EditText's

Tags: android, android-edittext, saving-data

I have a `Button` that creates `EditText`s dynamically. I'm not having any problems creating them when I run the app but none of the created `EditText`s are being saved when I close the app and reopen it. Here's my code:

```
 public class app extends ActionBarActivity {
     Button add;
     LinearLayout linearLayout1;
     static int createEditText;

     public static final String TAG = "MyPrefs" ;
     public static final String key1 = "numberOfEditTexts"; //Added this
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences; 

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);

        linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createEditText();
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void createEditText() {
        Log.i("ET", "ET created");
        createEditText++;
        if(createEditText > 6) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have reached the maximum fields",     
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }  

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 12, 0, 0);

        EditText edtTxt = new EditText(this);
        int maxLength = 8;
        edtTxt.setHint("New ET1");
        edtTxt.setLayoutParams(params);
        edtTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        edtTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME);
        edtTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
        InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
        fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        edtTxt.setFilters(fArray);
        edtTxt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(edtTxt);

        edtTxt.setId(createEditText);

    }


   @Override //Added this
   protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   Log.i("Pause", "onPause()");
   System.out.println("EditText = " + createEditText);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
   editor.putInt(key1, createEditText);
   editor.commit();
   }


  @Override //Added this
  protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  Log.i("Resume", "onResume()");
  System.out.println("EditText = " + createEditText);
  sharedPreferences.getInt(key1, createEditText);
  }
```

Comment: If you want to keep the data saved between various runs of the activity, you might like to read about `SharedPreferences` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static final String TAG = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String key1 = "numberOfEditTexts";
```

You should keep these two in your class first.  Next, create a `SharedPreference` object in the class.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

In your `onCreate()` method, initialize this:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And you can add the value to this either on your button press or on your `onPause` method.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt(key1, createEditText);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve this value at the beginning of the next time when you want to display the number of `EditText`s that you left the program with, do this:

```
storedNumber=editor.getInt(key1,0);
```

Similarly, if you want to store the contents of the `EditText`s, you could store them in the same `SharedPreference` object.

**Edit**

```
 @Override //Added this
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     Log.i("Resume", "onResume()");
     System.out.println("EditText = " + createEditText);
     //store the value in an integer.
     int prevVal = sharedPreferences.getInt(key1, 0);

     // now use this in a for loop.
     for (int i=0; i<prevVal; i++)
         createEditText();

 }
```

The `for` loop you added (running from 0 to 1) is not necessary.

Comment: Hey, @Anindya Dutta, I made the changes to my code but it's still not saving my created Edit Text's. I don't know, maybe I'm calling the shared prefs wrong. I made the changes to the post according to your suggestions. Can you please take a look at it and see where I'm going wrong? I can save the Edit Text that I have created in XML using shared prefs but I'm just stuck on trying to save the created Edit Text that's dynamically created. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to make two modifications.

1. `sharedPreferences.getInt(key1, createEditText);` should be saved in an `int` since it returns to you the number of `EditText` boxes.
2. You should make a for loop or something to call `createEditText()` that many number of times (the value that you get in 1.). Otherwise, even if you get the value, how would you populate the layout? :)

Comment: Okay, I'm kind of confused. Isn't `sharedPreferences.getInt(key1, createEditText);` already being saved as an `int`? I added the for loop to my code. Is it okay with you if you can show what you're trying to say, if possible? Thanks

Comment: `sharedPreferences.getInt(key1, createEditText);` means to assign the value in `key1` to an integer, if the key `key1` doesn't exist, then store in it a defined default value, which is the second parameter. In your case, this is not being saved. I have edited my post and added the code as to what I mean.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It is working very nicely. Thanks for all the help. So to save the data in the created `Edittext`, i can save it in the `sharedpreferences`? I think I can figure that one out by myself. Thanks again. I also checked out your profile and it took me to your blog, you do some really nice sketches. Very nicely written blog too. @Anindya Dutta

Comment: I can't upvote yet but I accepted your answer. @Anindya Dutta